# How do I add a band of color through the middle of a div with text and an image on top?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-position

I'm working on a webcomic for a client using React JS and Tailwind CSS. I'm designing little character descriptions, and this is the rough sketch he has given me

[image: client's sketch]

And this is what I have currently, with the code as well
[image: current design]

```
const CharacterItem = ({ name, isRevealed }) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex items-center font-comic gap-10 bg-white border border-black  mt-5">
      <img
        src={
          !isRevealed
            ? `/assets/cast/cast_${name}_silhouette.png`
            : `/assets/cast/cast_${name}.png`
        }
        className="h-1/12 w-1/12"
      />
      <div className="flex flex-col w-3/4 h-fit uppercase font-bold">
        <h3 className="text-3xl font-extrabold mt-5 mb-5">{name}</h3>
        <p className="text-xl bg-orange-400 p-7 w-full">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
          minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut
          aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
          reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
          pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
          culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CharacterItem
```

I've tried setting the p tags width to full, and removing padding from its container, but while it spans the full right side of its container, because they are in a flexbox it won't go past the image. Is there something I can do with relative or absolute positioning of the image to make this work?

Comment: Is the reactjs tag absolutely necessary? It seems to be a pure css/html issue.

Comment: you can make this work with absolute or fixed positioning, but it's a pain. I think a product like Adobe illustrator or just creating images might be the better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pseudo element on the paragraph, let's have a look at a quick example:

```css
.parent {
  --padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 2rem;
  padding: var(--padding);
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  position: relative;
}

p::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background: cyan;
  right: calc(var(--padding) * -1);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/200" class="image" />
  <div class="content">
    <h3>{name}</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
      in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `p::before` has few properties:

- `right: calc(var(--padding) * -1)` allows to move the box to the right of the container. `--padding` being the padding of the container.
- `width: 100vw` is just a width big enough to overflow the container.